# Error integrating with Redis: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, redis

My colleague shared a working java seed project with me (I'm a newcomer to java) that is caching the result of a Spring Boot service into a Redis in-memory store.  The service, which returned only one entity result, was based on a class of type `Mono`; but for my use case I need it to return a list, so I've been using a `Flux` type instead.

The service aspect of the code (including the use of the `Flux` type) was working until I attempted to cache the result to Redis running on my localhost.  Now I'm getting the following error and can't seem to understand how to fix it after a full day of Googling and troubleshooting.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable]
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/v1/walletcharges" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:96)
        ...
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:64)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43)
    ...
```

I understand the error well enough to guess (though I'm not certain) that the issue is coming from the two places where I've made a `Flux` from the iterable `walletCharges` `Flux.fromIterable(walletCharges)`.  But I don't know what to replace it with because converting it to a `Flux` was the only way I found to get rid of compilation errors caused by the mismatch of expected and returned types.

Following is my code.  My apologies for the length!  I've omitted the import statements for brevity, but because I don't know for sure where the issue is coming from, I felt nervous omitting anything else that might be relevant.

Please help me if you can!

**Main Application CitReconServiceApplication.java**

```
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
public class CitReconServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CitReconServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller WalletChargesController.java**

```
@Cacheable(value = "allWalletChargesCache", key = "#root.methodName")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"https://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000"} )
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/walletcharges")
public class WalletChargesController {

    private WalletChargesService _walletChargesService;

    @Autowired
    public WalletChargesController(WalletChargesService _walletChargesService) {
        this._walletChargesService = _walletChargesService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public Flux<WalletCharges> getWalletCharges() {
        return _walletChargesService.getWalletCharges();
    };
    
}
```

**Entity Model WalletCharges.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class WalletCharges implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(TRANSACTION_ID)
    private Integer transactionId;
    
    @JsonProperty(TYPE)
    private String type;
    
    // Other columns removed for brevity
}
```

**Redis Repository RedisWalletChargesRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class RedisWalletChargesRepository implements Serializable {
    
  private final ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> operations;

  public RedisWalletChargesRepository(ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> operations) {
    this.operations = operations;
  }

  public Flux<WalletCharges> save(String allWalletCharges, List<WalletCharges> walletCharges) {
    try {
      String walletChargesString = ObjectMapperUtils.convertToString(walletCharges);
      return operations.opsForValue()
          .set(allWalletCharges, walletChargesString)
          .flatMapMany(__ -> Flux.fromIterable(walletCharges));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  public Flux<WalletCharges> findByKey(String key) {
    return operations.opsForValue()
        .get(key)
        .flatMapMany(result ->  {
          try {
            List<WalletCharges> walletCharges = ObjectMapperUtils.convertToObject(result);
            return Flux.fromIterable(walletCharges);
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
          }
        });
  }
}
```

**Data Access Object WalletChargesRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface WalletChargesRepository extends JpaRepository<WalletCharges, Serializable> {

    @Query(value = GET_WALLET_CHARGES_SQL_LONGFORM, nativeQuery = true)
    List<WalletCharges> findAll();
}
```

**Service Implementation WalletChargesServiceImpl.javaa**

```
@Service
public class WalletChargesServiceImpl implements WalletChargesService {

    private WalletChargesRepository _repository;
    private RedisWalletChargesRepository _redisWalletChargesRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WalletChargesServiceImpl(WalletChargesRepository _repository, RedisWalletChargesRepository _redisWalletChargesRepository) {
        this._repository = _repository;
        this._redisWalletChargesRepository = _redisWalletChargesRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<WalletCharges> getWalletCharges() {
        return _redisWalletChargesRepository
        .findByKey("allWalletCharges")
        .switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> getWalletChargesFromDBAndCache()));
        
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<WalletCharges> getWalletChargesFromDBAndCache(){
        System.out.println("The getWalletChargesFromDBAndCache method was invoked");
        List<WalletCharges> walletCharges = _repository.findAll();
        _redisWalletChargesRepository.save("allWalletCharges", walletCharges);
        return Flux.fromIterable(walletCharges);

    }
}
```

**Object Mapper/Serializer ObjectMapperUtils.java**

```
@UtilityClass
public class ObjectMapperUtils {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper();

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    public <T> T convertValue(Object obj, Class<T> contentClass){
        return mapper.convertValue(obj, contentClass);
    }

    public String convertToString(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    }

    public List<WalletCharges> convertToObject(String str) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.readValue(str, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, WalletCharges.class));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you create rediscache configuration bean in configuration. if you're not created, please create it. don't add @Cachable on controller if you're using Responseentity. just add on service method. then add this configuration